# Error 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

this is my web config file. I tried to adjust this config as far as i know by info on net. but my site still error 403. Like this :

**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<!-- new added code -->
     <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
     </authorization>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Home.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
<!-- new added code -->
    </system.web>

  <!-- NEW ADDED
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

i have  no idea what things go wrong, because i am new to asp.net deploy to iis-things

Note :

- i did give full permissions for IIS_IUSR and Network Service on my path folder.
- some info said, Administrative Tools-> IIS Manager -> You Server Name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> Add MyDefaultPage.aspx. but i don't need any default page because my site only work when other site call its page and give specific response in url. so i leave my site without defaultpage

Comment: What is the request url you are trying to reach within your application?

Comment: Have you enabled Authentication Windows in the web.config file?

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

Comment: @mdowes www.mysitename.com , just it

Comment: no i have not, but is it necessary? @Ratheesh

Comment: If you are using windows authentication it is necessary.

Please see this link for your problem and undestanding https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

Comment: thanks mate . appreciate it @Ratheesh

Answer (score 2):

FOUND A SOLUTION . 
by Set a Default Document in Site-> Yoursites -> IIS Section. Chose default document sub menu and add your default page (in case you have not one ). Also by set Full permission for IIS_IUS and NETWORK SERVICE